# NGINX split config in multiple files

Tags: nginx, configuration

I am still learning NGINX and I came across one issue.
So before is start my project I am having issues with splitting the config file.
So the idea is to have one "main" file where server config is, example:

```
server {

    server_name demo.server.com;
    include my/custom/location/*.nginx;
}
```

So I have that file and the include file is:

```
location /pgadmin {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8190;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;


  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_request_buffering off;
}
```

I have service that's running on localhost:8190 and I am able to open the service over the public IP on the server. But when I want to open the service with demo.server.com/pgadmin I get the following [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQx2t.png).
I am doing this for sake of easier managing the configuration for the future.

Also I've trying the following configuration:

```
server {

server_name demo.server.com;

location /pgadmin {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8190;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;


      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
}
```

But I got the same error.
Any kind of help and explanation is welcome.

Comment: What do your nginx log files say? Also, include your error message in your post as text, and not as a link to an image.

Comment: Hi Bert, apologies for my sloppy work.
So this is the error that I see when I try to open the demo.server.com/pgadmin
ERROR 404
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."
And below you can see nginx access log.
"[17/Apr/2020:15:03:48 +0000] "GET /pgadmin HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0""
Error log:

Comment: And error log:
"2020/04/17 15:04:34 [error] 13111#13111: *3021 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: demo.server.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "demo.server.com"

That's all that I could get from access log and error log.

Comment: @Bert I've managed to figure out what was wrong.
I had to add / on "location /pgadmin/" and in proxy pass section "proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8190//;"
But now I have different kind of issue, whenever I login or open anything on demo.server.com/pgadmin/ it keeps redirecting me to root "demo.server.com"